# Jekyll filter to remove pages from site.pages based on page.url?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

While generating a Google site map for my (non-github) Jekyll site, I would like to exclude certain files based on the page URL (or file name). In shell-speak, something like

`site.pages | grep -v forbidden_name`

In Liquid, I imagine a signature something like

`site.pages | exclude 'url', forbidden_name`

In a related note, is there a catalog of the standard, built-in filters, tags, and generator? Something  a bit handier than `grep -Rl register_filter ~/.rvm/gems`?

Comment: Did you want to do it simple or plugin way ?

Comment: Simple, or existing plugin. I already know how to write such a filter, it just seems so obvious and basic I can't believe it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
    {% if p.url contains 'ca' %}
        {% comment %}Do nothing{% endcomment %}
    {% else %}
        {{ p.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

A little hacky an case unsensitive and no wild card.

I've made a [list of tags and filters](http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/tests/) that works on Github.

Comment: Can't believe this answer didn't recieve any upvoted. It is the correct answer. Upvoted it.